# Jersey gets stuck on resuming AsyncResponse

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

I have Jersey 2.15 service deployed in tomcat 8 on Windows, which receives POST requests and handles them async (via resuming AsyncResponse) and then returns ID to the client. All async operations are handled with ForkJoinPool operations.
 On my local dev environment I test service by POSTING data in 4 threads and everything is fine, but when I deploy my service on testing stand weirdness begins.

My service gets request from the client, successfully handles it, but then gets stuck on sending composed http response (enabled jersey logging filter ensures it) even if the client is deployed on that same machine. Also this service posts data via synchronous request with Jersey client API to another consumer - this request goes smoothly. Firewall is disabled and Wireshark shows that at least tcp handshakes go unharmed.

Did someone encounter something like this? Honestly I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Everything happened due the bug in latest Tomcat 8 versions. My local dev-environment had 8.0.14 version, testing stands had 8.0.18 and 8.0.21.